# How to pass my custom type values in fragment in kotlin?

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, android-viewpager

I am new to android, just a beginner in kotlin. I have android app with tab layout and viewpager. I have two fragments for two tabs. I need a some of values from main.kt to fragment.kt i don't know how to pass the values from main.kt to fragment.kt.

In my fragment.kt file i have a to call another class like this

```
recyclerView.adapter = TransactionRecyclerAdapter(transactionList,appDatabase,direction,networkDefinitionProvider)
```

this class must have a arguments so i need values from main.kt.

I unable to pass the values in bundle itself because the values return types like this

```
private val mfragmentAB = appDatabase
        private val mfragmentIT: List<TransactionEntity>? = it
        private val mfragmentINC : TransactionAdapterDirection? = incoming
        private val mfragmentnetwork : NetworkDefinitionProvider? = networkDefinitionProvider
        private val mfragmentviewpager : ViewPager? = viewPager
```

so the serialize and parcalable does not work. so plese guide me.

**main.kt**

```
private fun setupViewPager(viewPager: ViewPager, it: List<TransactionEntity>?, incoming: TransactionAdapterDirection) {
        val incomingData = ArrayList<TransactionEntity>()
        val outgoingData = ArrayList<TransactionEntity>()

        val adapter = ViewPagerAdapter(supportFragmentManager, viewPager, it, incoming, appDatabase, networkDefinitionProvider)
        if(incoming == INCOMING) {
            if (it != null) {
                incomingData.addAll(it)
            }
        }else {
            if (it != null) {
                outgoingData.addAll(it)
            }
        }
        adapter.addFragment(ReceiveFragment(), "SEND")
        adapter.addFragment(SendingFragment(), "RECEIVE")
        viewPager.adapter = adapter
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    class ViewPagerAdapter(manager: FragmentManager, viewPager: ViewPager?, it: List<TransactionEntity>?, incoming: TransactionAdapterDirection?, appDatabase: AppDatabase?, networkDefinitionProvider: NetworkDefinitionProvider?) : FragmentPagerAdapter(manager)
    {


        private val mFragmentList: ArrayList<Fragment> = ArrayList<Fragment>()
        private val mFragmentTitleList: ArrayList<String>  = ArrayList<String>()

        private val mfragmentAB = appDatabase
        private val mfragmentIT: List<TransactionEntity>? = it
        private val mfragmentINC : TransactionAdapterDirection? = incoming
        private val mfragmentnetwork : NetworkDefinitionProvider? = networkDefinitionProvider
        private val mfragmentviewpager : ViewPager? = viewPager

        override fun getCount(): Int {
            return mFragmentList.size
        }

         override fun getItem(position: Int): Fragment? {
             var fragment: Fragment? = null
             if (position == 0) {
                 fragment = SendingFragment()
             } else if (position == 1) {
                 fragment = ReceiveFragment()
             }
             return fragment
         }


        fun addFragment(fragment: Fragment, title: String) {
            mFragmentList.add(fragment)
            mFragmentTitleList.add(title)
        }

        override fun getPageTitle(position: Int): CharSequence? {
            return mFragmentTitleList[position]
        }

        override fun getItemPosition(fragItem: Any): Int {
            var position = 0
            if (fragItem is ReceiveFragment) {
                position = 0
            } else if (fragItem is SendingFragment) {
                position = 1
            }
            return if (position >= 0) position else PagerAdapter.POSITION_NONE
        }

    }
```

**frgment.kt**

```
class ReceiveFragment : Fragment(){


    private var linearLayoutManager: LinearLayoutManager? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    }

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {

        val rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.receive_fragment, container, false)
        val recyclerView = rootView.findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.transaction_recycler_in) as RecyclerView
        linearLayoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(), LinearLayout.VERTICAL, false)
        recyclerView.layoutManager = linearLayoutManager
        recyclerView.adapter = TransactionRecyclerAdapter(transactionList,appDatabase,direction,networkDefinitionProvider)
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        return rootView
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

```
companion object {
        /**
         * new instance pattern for fragment
         */
        @JvmStatic
        fun newInstance(myObject: List<TransactionEntity>?): ReceiveFragment {
            val newsFragment = ReceiveFragment()
            val args = Bundle()
            args.putParcelable(ARG_PARAM, myObject) ------**-Here i can not pass my values to onCreateView**
            return newsFragment
        }
    }
```

UPADTE -1

```
    companion object {
            /**
             * new instance pattern for fragment
             */
            @JvmStatic
            fun newInstance(myObject: List<TransactionEntity>?): ReceiveFragment {
                val gson = Gson()
                val model = myObject as List<TransactionEntity>
                val json = gson.toJson(model)
                System.out.println("json representation :" + json)
                val bundle = Bundle()
                bundle.putString("bundleValue", json)
                val receiveFragment: ReceiveFragment = ReceiveFragment()
                receiveFragment.setArguments(bundle)
                return receiveFragment
            }
        }

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {

            val gson = Gson()
            val parsedValue = arguments!!.getString("bundleValue")
 val turnsType = TypeToken<List<TransactionEntity>>() {}.type
        //val animals = gson.fromJson(parsedValue,turnsType )
            val animals = gson.fromJson(parsedValue, ) -------- how to get value here
```

and TypeToken is error show no constructor

Answer (score 1):

You can parse your objects using Gson() like this :

```
val parsedValue = Gson().toJson(value, object: TypeToken<StrangeType>(){}.type)
val bundle = Bundle()
bundle.putString("bundleValue", parsedValue)
val receiveFragment: ReceiveFragment = ReceiveFragment()
receiveFragment.setArguments(bundle)
```

and then in your fragment's `onCreateView()`

```
val parsedValue = arguments.getString("bundleValue")
val value: StrangeType = Gson().fromJson(parsedValue!!, object: TypeToken<StrangeType>(){}.type)
```

Where `StrangeType` is the type of object you want to send to Fragment.

Comment: okay i will try your code. I have a doubt in your code "val parsedValue = Gson().toJson(value, object: TypeToken<List<TransactionEntity>>(){}.type)"
1.here value is my args which is from instance ?
2. type unresolved error
3.TypeToken<List<TransactionEntity>>() no constructor errpr

Comment: value can be for example incomingData (i don't know what should be this transactionList):
`Gson().toJson(incomingData, object:TypeToken<ArrayList<TransitionEntity>>(){}.type`)

Answer (score 1):

Try this: TransactionEntity have to implement Serializable

```
fun newInstance(myObject: ArrayList<TransactionEntity>?): ReceiveFragment {
        val newsFragment = ReceiveFragment()
        val args = Bundle()
        args.putSerializable(ARG_PARAM, myObject) 
        return newsFragment
    }
```

and after:

```
arguments.getSerializable(ARG_PARAM) as ArrayList<TransactionEntity>
```